# Google Assistant - "Getting test version of" after Production Release

Tags: actions-on-google

Submitted actions for google production review and it has been approved.

Then I invoked the action but still, it is prompting "Getting the test version of *****" as the initial response and then the welcome message.

Please provide the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is just happening for you, and possibly for anyone who is in the Alpha or Beta channels.

You can go into the simulator and indicate which version you want to use. This will apply for both the simulator *and* devices linked with the same account. If you have the new simulator, you can select "Settings"

[image]

then select which version you should use from the dropdown.

[image]

Alpha and Beta channel users can go to the same URL they used to connect to the channel and indicate they want to switch to the production version.